# Don't make functions within a loop no-loop-func -React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to find index of array using lodash locationbar. but my react console showing some warnings. can be resolve?

```
let wishListData = wishList.result;
                let j = 0; const jMax = wishListData.length;
                for (; j < jMax; j++) {

                    var index = _.findIndex(products.result, function (product) {
                        return product.id === wishListData[j]['pid']
                    });

                    if (index !== -1) {
                        products.result[index]['isWishList'] = true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func

Comment: What warning do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over `wishList.result` with `forEach` instead of a `for` loop, and you'll avoid the warning:

```
wishListData.forEach(({ pid }) => {
  const index = _.findIndex(products.result, ({ id }) => id === pid);
  if (index !== -1) {
    products.result[index].isWishList = true;
  }
});
```

Note that this is a *linter warning*, not a Javascript error. Your code works, the linter just considers it to be confusing - better to use array methods instead of loops when possible.

Also, feel free to remove the `_` library and just use built-in Javascript methods instead, if you want:

```
wishListData.forEach(({ pid }) => {
  const product = products.result.find(({ id }) => id === pid);
  if (product) {
    product.isWishList = true;
  }
});
```

Or, for an `O(N)` solution instead of an `O(N^2)` solution, figure out all `pid`s first, then iterate over the products:

```
const pids = new Set(wishListData.map(({ pid }) => pid));
products.result.forEach((product) => {
  if (pids.has(product.id)) {
    product.isWishList = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: May as well also boot lodash and use `products.result.findIndex(({ id }) => id === pid);`

Comment: For...of loops are more readable than forEach, using it just to satisfy linter false positive seems crazy.

Comment: I prefer `for..of` too, but sometimes people are in an environment where they can't change linter settings

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this as well:

- Instead of mutating `product` in `products.result[index]['isWishList'] = true;`, you should create new object to minimize side-effect.
- Also, instead of looping on `wishListData`, you can create a list of PIDs and just check index. If this list is created outside, you can create list of PIDs outside as well. That will reduce processing it every time

```js
const wishListPID = wishList.result.map((x) => x.pid);
const result = products.result.map((product) => {
  const isWishList = wishListPID.indexOf(product.id) !== -1;
  return { ...product, isWishList }
});
```